# Change MS Office Button Icon

Tags: ms-access, ribbon

Has anyone found a way to change the icon displayed in the Office Button in A2007?

Having converted an MS Access 2003 app to 2007, it's very annoying that **my** app is now displayed as an MS Office app instead!

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly hide all of the ribbon and the office button with one line of VBA code in your startup. You can use:

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

The above will hide the office button the QAT and the ribbon.

edit:
You were asking how to hide everything. It is just a simple great one of code that will accomplish this for you.

If you are looking to build a custom UI, then you are free to do so. About the only limitation of a custom ribbon is you HAVE to have file button (but, I think every program I installed for 15+ years had a file option anyway).

So, you are most free to customize what that file button shows.  You question simply asked how to hide everything and the above does that with ease.

So, if you do want a ribbon, then your custom ribbon can specify startfromScratch = true, then the only UI options you add to your ribbon is what the user will see.

However, a custom ribbon will always have the file button (or what we often call pizza button and that simply part of the ribbon).

You can also consider using menu bars and not showing the pizza button, but 2007 does not have a built in menu bar builder like previous versions did. This abilty to show only a custom menu bar is outlined here:

http://www.accessribbon.de/en/index.php?FAQ:7

Comment: Albert, I had come across that before, but it then doesn't allow any kind of menu at all... not the QAT, nor a Ribbon, etc. Or am I missing a trick?

Comment: Thanks Albert. After converting the app to 2007, I have since managed to create my own custom ribbons. It appears the MS logo on the 'pizza button' just cannot be changed.